# Issues with monitor with HDMI

Tags: debian, hdmi, external-display

I use a KVM switch to share my 27 inch monitor between my work laptop (window) and my personal thinpc Asus PN50 with Ryzen running the latest Debian.

My Monitor works fine with my laptop but not with my thin pc. I get a blank screen. I have a 4 port KVM, i am tried switching to different ports, that is definitely not the problem. I even tried connecting to the thinPC directly and bypassing the KVM altogether, even that did not make a difference. If i connect a VGA cable from the thinPC to the monitor, i get display but that is not useful as i need KVM functionality to switch between inputs.

I tried switching HDMI cables, that did not help either.  this is a setup that was working fine earlier.  This is a problem that materialized in recent times.  Is this something caused by a bad driver or settings on debian because of an update. will something like modprobe help?

When i connect using VGA, when i go to display settings, it actually shows the other display as display 2 HDMI.  but if i use CMD+P to switch to it, i get a blank screen as usual.  So the device is very much connected but its only the display output that's the issue.

display refresh rate is 60hz which it says is auto selected as the only supported option (which it detects, yet no display itself)

**Update:** The HDMI port must have been the issue.  I ordered a USB C DP to HDMI adapter dongle and it worked like a charm.  Just plugged it in and my display is working perfectly. Maybe there was a way to fixing this issue without the adapter but it did not cost me a lot so quite pleased

Comment: the specs for your PC indicate DisplayPort. are you using any adapters? if so are they "active" adapters?

Comment: why are you adding confusion to your question by talking about the KVM, when the KVM is irrelevant to the problem?

Comment: Right now it's pure hdmi end to end.  But I've ordered a usb c dp to HDMI adapter to see if my HDMI port is somehow the problem.  Someone had suggested it could be an electrical grounding issue but I don't know how to validate that.

Comment: the adapter worked.  Updated the OP